# JDK 8 Installation for Ubuntu 14.04 (Android Studio & NetBeans)

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, jdk, netbeans

I downloaded `jdk-8u11-nb-8-linux-i586.sh` and installed it in my home folder. Then I install NetBeans, it is successful I think because I can compile my java code using netbeans. Now when I install android studio, it says

`No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.`

I tried adding environmental variables,

`export JAVA_HOME=/home/port8080/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/home/port8080/jdk1.8.1.0_11/bin`

but when I tried `java -version` my installed jdk is still not detected. Now I am going to install java via `apt-get`.

Is it okay to install via apt-get at the same time I already installed it in home? how can I fix this so I can work with netbeans which requires jdk from my home folder?

I am also, thinking that when I finish installing jdk via apt-get it will install in /usr/ .

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/55960/44179
If that doesn't help (especially `update-alternatives`), delete your jdk8 installation and install it using this PPA: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
Unless you only need Java 7, then the easiest solution would be to simply install OpenJDK7 from the repository...

Answer (score 1):

If you change the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables as below you should be able to access your local installation.

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/home/port8080/jdk1.8.0_11/bin
  export PATH=/home/port8080/jdk1.8.1.0_11/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: So you mean, I don't need to download it again using apt-get since I already installed it in home folder. How about the `JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: Yes. JAVA_HOME is ok.

Comment: still not working, android studio still cannot find JAVA_HOME

Comment: Sorry, can you delete /java at the end of HOME_JAVA line.

Comment: @Port8080: Which file are you using to set those environment variables?